# I've got a definition, but says something strange, what does it mean?

Tags: metric-spaces, continuity

$M_1:=(M,d_1), \ \  M_2:=(M,d_2)$.  $d_1$ is equivalent to $d_2$ if the identity $x\rightarrow x$ of $M_1$ **over** $M_2$ is an homeomorphism

I'm not sure what it is talkin about when it says "identity" becasue the "$x\rightarrow x$" confuses me a bit, also, if it's an identity why does it point out 2 different sets with the word "over" (in bold)?

Comment: It is the identity on $M$ but with respect to the topologies induced by the two different metrics. If that map sends open sets to open sets and it's inverse (which for the identity is just the same map) does so as well, then the two metrics are equivalent - essentially defining the same topology on $M$.

Comment: So a set may be open wrt. to $M_1$ but not wrt. $M_2$ or vice versa. But if the two metrics define the same open sets on $M$, they are equivalent.

Comment: How do i link this identity to the metric?
I've got to prove that $d_1=|x-y|$ and $d_2=|x^3-y^3|$ are equivalent in $\mathbb{R}$. i have no idea how to proceed

Comment: Do you know about [topologies induced by metrics](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MetricTopology.html)?

Comment: Oh god i feel so bad, i don't understand :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "over" in the quoted definition sounds strange; so let's forget about it.

A *homeomorphism*  $f: X \to Y$ is a bijective map between toplogical spaces whereby both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ are continuous. This is the same as a bijective map whereby both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ send open sets to open sets.

In the example at hand one and the same "ground set" $M$ carries two different metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$. Each of these metrics establishes on $M$ a corresponding topology that determines which sets $A\subset M$ are open, or which functions $g:\>M\to{\mathbb R}$ are continuous, etc. The two metrics are called *equivalent* if they induce the same toplogy on $M$. This means that the measured distances may be very different for the two metrics, but when it comes to openness of sets $A$ or continuity of functions on $M$ there is no difference.

This is the case iff any $d_1$-neighborhood $U^{d_1}_\epsilon(p):=\{x\in M\>|\> d_1(x,p)<\epsilon\}$ of any point $p\in M$ contains a $d_2$-neighborhood $U^{d_2}_{\epsilon'}(p)$ for a suitable $\epsilon'$, and vice versa.

Now a fancy way of expressing this condition is the following: The map $$\iota: \quad(M,d_1)\to(M,d_2),\qquad x\mapsto x$$
is a homeomorphism.